# Oxyplot move all Axis labels by a custom constraint

Tags: winforms, axis-labels, oxyplot, yaxis

I have a problem with **OxyPlot** (Windows form) Axis labels: I'd like to move y Axis label by a custom constraint, for example put all labels where indicated by arrows in the figure:

[image: ylabelPosition]

Something like `Axis.LabelPadding = 10;`

The `Axis` is a `CategoryAxis` with `Position = AxisPosition.Left`, nothing else.
How should I add a padding to *each* label of my axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you have to use `IsTickCentered = true` property when you define your `CategoryAxis`.

```
new CategoryAxis { IsTickCentered = true };
```